# Laravel query builder inject column value into Carbon query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder, php-carbon

I've got a query that I'm running in my project on a model called `Domain`, it returns all domains where the status column of a domain matches **complete** and a date column is before or equal to a specific set of days.

I've recently refactored the model columns and have included a new column called `domain_alert_period` which is an integer column that holds a value in days, I need to somehow target this column and put it in replace of my existing **30** so that the user is able to control the number of days prior to getting an alert.

What am I missing from this to achieve this?

```php
return Domain::where('status', 'complete')
            ->where(function ($sql) {
              $sql->where('domain_expires_on', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)) // 2 days after expiry
                  ->where('domain_expires_on', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(30)); // 30 days before expiry
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Determining what your desired SQL query is would be a good start...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries) in your clause to use raw DB expressions, If its MySQL you can use `DATE_ADD` method with your column value for comparision

```
$sql->where('domain_expires_on', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)) // 2 days after expiry
    ->whereRaw('domain_expires_on < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL domain_alert_period DAY)');
```

Comment: your suggestion is good but condition is wrong. As in whereRaw condition you are adding a days to `domain_expires_on` and comparing the same for lesser.. It will always be lasser.. its like 1 < 1+2 always.

Comment: @RuchitaSheth yes you are right, I had missed that part thank you for the correction

Answer (score 2):

- A mysql DATE_SUB function should be used to subtract days from a `domain_expires_on` date. so that will be a date you should start an alert from
- And then match a current date is greater or equal to that alert date

  ```
  $query = $this->model
                ->whereRaw('CURDATE() <= DATE_ADD(`domain_expires_on` , INTERVAL 2 DAY)') // till 2 days after expiry
                ->whereRaw('CURDATE() >= DATE_SUB(`domain_expires_on` , INTERVAL domain_alert_period DAY)')
                ->get();
  ```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question correctly what you can do is use `use ($var)` in your query to replace 30

```
$start=1; //you can also take date from user for between like `date_from` and `date_to` and parse them with Carbon insted of adding or substracting days from now()
$end=30;
return Domain::where('status', 'complete')
->where(function ($sql) use ((int) $start,(int) $end) {
     $sql->whereDate('domain_expires_on', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays($start)->toDateString())
     ->whereDate('domain_expires_on', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays($end)->toDateString());
})
->get();
```

Also if you are storing `domain_expires_on` only as the date you should format the carbon date to match your database format.

above method will work for `$table->date('domain_expires_on');` and `$table->dateTime('domain_expires_on');`